# Accessing Name, Firstname... from a VObject in Python

Tags: python, extract, vcf-vcard, vobject

I might be very stupid here, and my knowledge about Python is nearly at 0.

I get a vcard from my Mac Contacts - I can access it and transform most of the data. Simple outputs are easy. I lack when I want to access data which is divided - I would call it an array, or dict or list...

Simple task: I want to get the first name, last name and middle name: Here is my test card:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Doe;John;;;
FN:John Doe
ORG:Example.com Inc.;
TITLE:Imaginary test person
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=WORK;type=pref:johnDoe@example.org
TEL;type=WORK;type=pref:+1 617 555 1212
TEL;type=WORK:+1 (617) 555-1234
TEL;type=CELL:+1 781 555 1212
TEL;type=HOME:+1 202 555 1212
item1.ADR;type=WORK:;;2 Enterprise Avenue;Worktown;NY;01111;USA
item1.X-ABADR:us
item2.ADR;type=HOME;type=pref:;;3 Acacia Avenue;Hoemtown;MA;02222;USA
item2.X-ABADR:us
NOTE:John Doe has a long and varied history\, being documented on more police files that anyone else. Reports of his death are alas numerous.
item3.URL;type=pref:http\://www.example/com/doe
item3.X-ABLabel:_$!<HomePage>!$_
item4.URL:http\://www.example.com/Joe/foaf.df
item4.X-ABLabel:FOAF
item5.X-ABRELATEDNAMES;type=pref:Jane Doe
item5.X-ABLabel:_$!<Friend>!$_
CATEGORIES:Work,Test group
X-ABUID:5AD380FD-B2DE-4261-BA99-DE1D1DB52FBE\:ABPerson
END:VCARD
```

So the field I want to get is "N" - so when I try:

```
vcard.n.value
```

I get:  `John  Doe`

```
vCard.n.value.family
```

I get: `Doe`

```
vcard.n.value.name
```

I get:

> AttributeError: 'Name' object has no attribute 'name'

```
vCard.n
```

I get: `<N{} John  Doe >`

So what's this structure: <N{} John  Doe > ??

Could somebody give me a few hints?

I want to extract first and last name from a VCF with Vobject. But I can only get the full name (fn) or the name with some spaces.

Comment: `vCard.n` is an instance of the `Name` class, and `<N{} John Doe>` is how the class defines its printed representation.

Comment: In Python, classes can customize the string and printed representation of their instances, by defining `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the support. So this instance of 'Name' carries a String ' John Doe' - it does not make any difference at all? I thought this might be an array, dict or list and I can access the different values.

Comment: Look at the documentation of the `vObject` library, it should tell you the classes of all its objects.

Answer (score 0):

In vobject, values of N are structured, as you've discovered.

The attributes of interest are:

- prefix
- given
- additional
- family
- suffix

So in the specific case you mention, you'd want

```
vcard.n.value.given
```

to get the "John" value for "John Doe".

You can discover this by using the `dir()` function at the interpreter prompt.

```
>>> import vobject
>>> vcard = vobject.newFromBehavior('vcard')
>>> n = vcard.add('n')
>>> dir(n.value)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'additional', 'family', 'given', 'prefix', 'suffix', 'toString']
>>>
```

The attributes with double underscore prefix/suffix are basically implementation details of the language/interpreter.  The `toString` attribute is an internal vobject function for stringifying a list.